# How to use proxy on Virtual Box (Windows XP)

Tags: networking, windows-xp, virtualbox, proxy, adapter

I'm not exactly the most tech savy so please bear with me. I am trying to connect through a proxy with my Virtualbox accounts.

Initially I wanted to just set the browsers in each virtualbox under a proxy but my boss said that it can probably be done right off the bat under the virtualbox accounts itself. Could anyone guide me on how to do this?

All the instructions online state that their should be a proxy setting in preferences however all I see is a Network Adapter tab.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "virtualbox accounts".  If your asking if you can configure virtualbox to use a proxy, I am not aware of a feature like that, can you provide more information.  Ask your boss for the information if you can't provide it yourself.

Comment: Yep, I am asking if I can use virtualbox to use a proxy. My boss only has a vague idea about it, we were figuring out a way to solve this but couldn't find a solution so I'm asking online now :) 

By accounts I meant, each windows XP user I created in Virtual Box

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that VirtualBox supports a global proxy setting that applies transparently to all your guest operating systems, or even certain ones. That would definitely be convenient.

You should be able to open Internet Explorer in your guest OS, configure the proxy in the same way that your host OS is configured. (Some Linux guest operating systems are a little trickier because you have to set environment variables in .bashrc, aptitude config files for Ubuntu, etc.)